# linux не работает командный файл sed

Tags: linux, unix, sed

У меня есть каталог со структурой:

```
0   ./arg3/arg2/arg5/arg6
0   ./arg3/arg2/arg5
0   ./arg3/arg2/arg1
0   ./arg3/arg2
0   ./arg3
120 .
```

Я пытаюсь создать командный файл, и с помощью sed исполнить следующие действия:
над данными файла s3  определить образец для одного поля строки из одного или более повторов малых символов латинского алфавита произвести замену путем выделения скобками и утроения определенного поля.

что у меня есть:

```
man du > arg3/arg2/arg1/s3
vi com2
chmod a+x com2
PATH=$PATH:~/name
cat arg3/arg2/arg1/s3
com2
cat arg3/arg2/arg1/f7
```

текст com2: `sed 's/[a-z]\+/(&&&)/' ~/name/arg3/arg2/arg1/s3 > ~/name/arg3/arg2/arg1/f7`

не могу понять, где ошибся, в файле f7 нет никаких изминений. буду благодарен за помощь!

Comment: у вас путаница s7 c f7

Comment: После вашей правки все заработало, как вы ожидали?

Comment: @avp увы, нет:(

Comment: Вот это -- `sed 's/[a-z]\+/(&&&)/'` во всех строках файла утраивает **первую** цепочку (именно первую, а не все. Т.е. из `1 abc 2 qwe 3 rty` получите `1 (abcabcabc) 2 qwe 3 rty`)  маленьких букв. Если это не совсем то, что вы хотели, то постарайтесь объяснить в тексте вопроса (можно с рядом примеров), что именно вам нужно, с какими данными запускаете и что в результате видите.

Answer (score 0):

не совсем понятна логика использования здесь

```
PATH=$PATH:~/name
```

для *одноразового* использования вполне будет достаточно запускать скрипт как

```
./com2
```

или

```
bash com2
```

если запускать с другого места то просто добавить путь

```
./путь/к/скрипту/com2
```

ели же хотите чтобы скрипт был **постоянно** доступен для вашей оболочки `bash/zsh` с которой вы *работаете* в консоли то закиньте его в одно из мест указанных в переменной `$PATH` что сделает его доступным сразу для всех пользователей системы.

Если же вы при этом хотите чтобы скрипт был доступен **только для пользователя** под которым сидите то для этого рекомендуется использовать папку `~/.local/bin/`

> Executables that shall appear in the user's $PATH search path. It is
> recommended not to place executables in this directory that are not
> useful for invocation from a shell; these should be placed in a
> subdirectory of ~/.local/lib/ instead. Care should be taken when
> placing architecture-dependent binaries in this place, which might be
> problematic if the home directory is shared between multiple hosts
> with different architectures.

согласно [Vendor package file locations under the home directory of the user](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/file-hierarchy.html#User%20Packages)

если по каким-то причинам папка `~/.local/bin/` не присутствует в переменной `$PATH` то её следует туда добавить, для этого просто прописав в конце файла(`~/.bashrc` или `~/.zshrc` для `bash` и `zsh` соответственно) вашей оболочки следующее

```
PATH=$PATH:$HOME/.local/bin
```

естественно вам никто не запрещает прописать любую другую папку, хоть туже `~/name`, но поверьте если это игра в долгую то со временем внесёт много путаницы особенно с таким подходом к названию и использованию не по назначению, как то `~/name/arg3/arg2/arg1/s3` ...

В общем, как это по нормальному должно выглядеть, для примера:

```
$ rm -rf arg3; mkdir -p arg3/arg2/arg1;man du > arg3/arg2/arg1/s3; tree arg3
arg3
└── arg2
    └── arg1
        └── s3

2 directories, 1 file
```

создадим вложенные папки с `arg3` по `arg1` и в *последней* создадим файл `s3` куда поместили ман по утилите `du`

проверяем, работает ли данная команда так как нам нужно:

```
sed 's/[a-z]\+/(&&&)/' arg3/arg2/arg1/s3 > arg3/arg2/arg1/f7
```

если всё ок, то записываем её в скрипт и делаем его исполняемым:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

sed 's/[a-z]\+/(&&&)/' arg3/arg2/arg1/s3 > arg3/arg2/arg1/f7
```

теперь допустим что нам нужно запускать скрипт не только от текущего местоположения или заранее прописанного абсолютного пути (как то ~/name/arg3/arg2/arg1/s3), для этого введём дополнительную переменную `DIR` и привяжем к ней путь к скрипту

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

DIR="${0%/*}"
sed 's/[a-z]\+/(&&&)/' $DIR/arg3/arg2/arg1/s3 > $DIR/arg3/arg2/arg1/f7
```

теперь мы можем запустить скрипт как

```
./путь/к/скрипту/com2
```

но здесь всё еще будет привязка расположения самого скрипта и той же начальной папки `arg3`, то есть по простому мы хотим отвязаться от указания как абсолютного пути в самом скрипте так и от расположения скрипта и обрабатываемой папки. Для этого изменем немного наш скрипт:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

DIR="$1"
sed 's/[a-z]\+/(&&&)/' $DIR/s3 > $DIR/f7
```

здесь мы переменной `DIR` присваиваем первый(`$1`) аргумент идущий после нашей команды `com2` где естественно будем указывать нужный нам путь.
Ну и под конец можно уже это скрипт легко перенести в рекомендованную директорию

```
mv com2 $HOME/.local/bin/
```

а после без всяких приставок по типу `./` и местоположения самого скрипта, запускать:

```
com2 arg3/arg2/arg1
```

или

```
com2 /путь/к/папке/arg3/arg2/arg1
```